# FreeBSD quarterly binaries mariadb101-server missing, why?

Tags: mariadb, freebsd, binaries

On FreeBSD 11.1 I am having problems building mariadb101-server. So as a last resort I thought I might grab the binary from the quarterly (kids, you should normally not mix ports with packages) repo, but there's no package for **mariadb101-server**:

http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:11:amd64/quarterly/All/

Why is it not there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the `latest`:

```
http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:11:amd64/latest/All/
```

The `mariadb101-server`:

```
http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:11:amd64/latest/All/mariadb101-server-10.1.33.txz
```

The reasons for why is not listed in the `quarterly` seems to be because some  critical vulnerabilities, you can read more about it here: https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=219045

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I've missed that.

I am reluctant about going on latest because my ports tree is on quarterly.